# The foreign key property 'fk1' was created in shadow state because a conflicting property with the simple name 'property'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, relationship, .net-6.0, code-first

I'm creating my database using code-first and entity framework core, I have a 1:1 relationship, but in this relationship, I have a navigation property in both entities, this is my first entity:

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public virtual Mac Mac { get; set; }
        public virtual Gender Gender { get; set; }        
    }
```

and this is my second entity:

```
public class Mac
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public HashSet<MacsUsers> MacsUsers { get; set; }
        public string UserEmail { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is my dbContext configuration:

```
builder.Entity<User>().HasOne(u => u.Mac)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey<Mac>(g => g.UserEmail);
```

THE REASON why I have these navigation properties in both entities is that I have a query in which I retrieve data from Mac by using User entity like this:

```
foreach (var item in ListTupla)
                {
                    item.CreationDate = listUser.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Mac.Id == item.MacId).Mac.User.CreationDate;
                    item.MacUserTalked = listUser.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Mac.Id == item.MacId).Mac.User.Email;//here Mac.User
                    item.MacUserWhoTalks = listUser.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Mac.Id == item.MacId).Email;
                    item.Name = listUser.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Mac.Id == item.MacId).Mac.User.Name; //here Mac.User
```

this is exactly the message warning: The foreign key property 'Mac.UserEmail1' was created in shadow state because a conflicting property with the simple name 'UserEmail' exists in the entity type, but is either not mapped, is already used for another relationship, or is incompatible with the associated primary key type. See https://aka.ms/efcore-relationships for information on mapping relationships in EF Core

I have found a solution is putting the virtual in the navigation property but it does not work for me, any comment?

Comment: `.WithOne()` -> `.WithOne(m => m.User)`

Answer (score 1):

I added public `virtual` in front of my reference navigation properties and it solved the issue.[image: See this image please]

Answer (score 0):

My relationship was that a project has many fileDataLinks and fileDataLink has navigation properties back to project. It needed to have the one to many relationship defined booth ways. The Fluent API needed to have the relationship defined to not create shadow navigation properties, e.g. ProjectId1, like the below.

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
            .HasMany( e => e.FileDataLinks )
            .WithOne( e => e.Project )
            .HasForeignKey( e => e.ProjectId )
            .HasPrincipalKey( e => e.Id )
            .OnDelete( DeleteBehavior.NoAction );
        modelBuilder.Entity<FileDataLink>()
            .HasOne( s => s.Project )
            .WithMany( g => g.FileDataLinks )
            .HasForeignKey( s => s.ProjectId )
            .OnDelete( DeleteBehavior.NoAction );
```